# How to use APKTool to extract the apk files without baksmaliing (Exactly as unzip do)

Tags: android, apktool

What is the option for apktool to extract the dex file without backsmalling the dex file.

Comment: @BobMalooga That's not right at all. I use apktool regularly to learn how stuff are implmented in apps. Sometimes I've used it to patch and fix some really old apps that crash on recent versions of Android. I don't feel like a thief honestly.

Comment: @LucaD'Amico Mind to read the post tags? What does `reverse engineering` suggest you?

Comment: @BobMalooga in my opinion, reverse engineering has nothing to do with stealing other people's works. It is more like binary analysis. Antivirus and software security company use reverse engineering to study virus behaviours. People like me use reverse engineering to study how software works and to fix crash in old software. Opensource supporters often use reverse engineering to study how closed source drivers works and then rewrite them. Reverse engineering has (almost) nothing to do with "cracking" and software thiefs.

Comment: @LucaD'Amico `Reverse engineering has (almost) nothing to do with "cracking" and software thiefs.` This is **completely wrong**. Reverse enginieering is the **primary tool** for crackers and digital thieves. Therefore, it has **everything to do** with them.

Comment: Points of view. I've written enough examples to prove that reverse engineering is used day by day for good reasons and ethical purpose. Anyway I respect your point of view.

Comment: I've never imagined this question could raise so much controversy. Seriously, I should thank @BobMalooga for making me aware of the facts that 'apktool'  could be used to do cracking work. However, it is not sufficient for accusing me of stealing someone else's work without even asking me what am I am doing with this tool. Finally, thanks Luca, you have said what I want to express.

Comment: If you use apkTool, it means that you don't have the source code. If you don't, then you should not even try to reverse engineer someone else's work. AT LEAST, you are infringing their intellectual property (ever heard about copyright?). If someone doesn't give you the source and they don't EXPLICITLY allow you to disassemble their work, well... that's **illegal**.

Comment: @BobMalooga, Thanks Bob, I really appreciate your point of view. I am always supporting you on protecting the copyright. What I have to make it clear is, the app manufacturer know we are testing and they even gave us cooperations. If this question disturbs you or makes you feel bad, I will delete it. THANKS.

Comment: `the app manufacturer know we are testing and they even gave us cooperations.` If they were cooperating, they would give you the **source code**, not the compiled app.

Comment: @BobMalooga I don't think asking how to use apkTool implies anything. I can use apkTool to decomile my own apk to verify proguard settings, or determine how easy it can be for real "hackers" to steal password in decompiled code. These are legitimate usage of apkTool to decompile an apk.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy The OP admitted to be reverse engineering an app which does not belong to them. `the app manufacturer know we are testing and they even gave us cooperations.`

Comment: @BobMalooga you said: that's illegal. No, that's not illegal, at least in my country. We are allowed to study software using reverse engineering techniques when the source code is not available. It is illegal to circumvent copy protection. Here on stack exchange we also have a reverse engineering FAQ community: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LucaD'Amico It may be not illegal only for educational purposes. You're then not allowed to re-use what you have extracted from the compiled program.

Comment: @BobMalooga Sure, but I gain the knowledge, and then I can write my own code (hopefully knowledge can't be copyrighted). That's how the ethical Reverse Engineering (also called "Clean Room")  works. Many opensource drivers are written this way.

Comment: @LucaD'Amico `... knowledge can't be copyrighted...` So, can music be copyrighted? can art be copyrighted? can code be copyrighted? I say YES, of course they can.

Comment: @BobMalooga those are works, not knowledge.

Comment: @LucaD'Amico Also software is WORK. Not everyone does it for fun like you do

Comment: @BobMalooga Why you suppose that I code for fun? I'm a professional developer. I don't code for fun. I Reverse Engineer for fun. Anyway, that's my point of view. I'm not doing anything illegal (as I've stated eralier, in my country reversing for education purpose and for learning is perfectly legal). No Flame wanted, just PEACE.. We are here to learn togheter afterall :)

Comment: @LucaD'Amico You say so, But you steal information. And information has a cost, in this world. Therefore, what you do is perfectly illegal.

Comment: God please forgive me then..

Comment: @God: Forgive him... **not**.

Comment: @BobMalooga, As far as I am concerned, you are accussing me of 'using apktool to analyze app without source code'. If so, shall I asking the app writer for source code? If all the app writers agree to share its source code when there is someone saying he is analyzing the code, then there would be no privacy problems, no clone apps, no malwares.

Comment: ... and **no need to use apkTool**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself,

the option seems to be **-s**

When you are using apkstudio, you can choose to decompile or not, if you choose not to decompile, the command line would add the **-s** option

That is:

```
apktool d -s yourapk.apk -o yourfolder
```